# Compiler can't find libswresample library

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm currently trying to compile [this](https://github.com/Splamy/TS3AudioBot) teamspeak bot on Ubuntu. My issue is that when trying to compile it, I get the following error:

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.0/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:136 (message):
  Could NOT find FFmpeg (missing: SWRESAMPLE_LIBRARIES
  SWRESAMPLE_INCLUDE_DIRS)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.0/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:343 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  cmake/FindFFmpeg.cmake:90 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:35 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/opt/TS3AudioBot/TS3AudioBob/bin/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

As you can see, it cannot find the libswresample library. However, I've installed a number of packages which as far as I know should work: libswresample-ffmpeg-dev and libswresample-ffmpeg-1. After installing both of these, I still get the same error. I'm aware of Ubuntu using the libav fork of ffmpeg in the past, but I thought they had decided to switch back on 15.04.

Comment: I hope you are aware that 15.04 has reached the end of lifetime, and normally isn't supported here anymore, so my suggestion is an upgrade to a newer version. I considered close voting but left it as it is because it might be beneficial for future readers.

Comment: How about the main  libswresample ? ... i.e.  `libswresample-dev`

Comment: @KnudLarsen I don't think that's included in the 15.04 repositories.

Comment: Right, for 15.04 it is libswresample-ffmpeg-dev , that contains the "development files".  ( Is different from Ubuntu version 15.10 )-.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77096790/why-c-app-fail-because-of-shared-library) more details about this problem.